# Install fails, cannot mount swap

Tags: 10.04, installation, swap

I am trying to fresh install a box to 10.04 (it was previously 9.10), but during the install process mounting the swap partition fails giving the error:

> The attempt to mount a file system
>   with type swap in SCSI4 (0,0,0),
>   partition #5 (sda) at none failed.
>
> You may resume partitioning from the
>   partitioning menu.

I ran the short-smart tools on it which returned no errors on the disk, its a relatively new disk.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select manual partitioning and create one huge partition format it as `ext4` and mount it as `/`

Then left about 2-3 GB of space for a swap partion (WHICH YOU DON'T CREATE YET)

```
|-----------------------|
|Root FS /     | free2GB|
|-----------------------|
```

Then proceed and ubuntu asks if you are sure not to create swap. Say Yes.

I the system now works fine and you can use it, you can create the swap afterwards

For example: Start `gparted` and create an swap parition in the freespace

Then do a `swapon /dev/sdXXX` (XXX the newly created partition)

Now you can check if this has worked with `free`
If everythink works you can add the swap to the `fstab` file to be automounted after a restart.